# How to populate a dropdown list based on a table field in Google AppMaker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm creating an app that will search my CloudSQL DB and return some rows, i need some filters using DropDown lists based on existing values in DB.

For Example: I have projects A, B and C, my dropdown should show A,B,C as options to take.

My table is working fine, i've tried to set up some codes in the dropdown options item but nothing worked

I've tried to this in the options of the dropdown:

`@datasources.Atividades.model.fields.Cod_Projeto.possibleValues`

and with other paths appmaker don't let me confirm and continue.

I just need the dropdown to show the values dynamically, from time to time new projects will be created and the dropdown should show them as well

Comment: I think a binding for `@datasources.projects.items` should work for your case and then maybe set the dropdown names to `@datasources.projects.items..name`. You might need to provide some more detail in regards to your setup though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Markus! My mistake was at the "items" componente, i was trying to use the "item" without the "s" and wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Found the error!

I was trying to use the "Item" component when i should be using the "Items" for it to work